# Making a extra charge on purchase NgxStripe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using NgxStripe to create a subscription purchase, but in the new version of the app they want to make a extra charge it have 1 or 5 extra charges.

My question is how can i make this. How can I add the extra cost? I understand I need to make the subscription first and then the extra payout, I was seeing the NgxStripe Docs but I don't see something about payouts

My actual code is:

```
const name = this.stripeTest.get('name').value;
    this.stripeService
      .createToken(this.card.element, { name })
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.token) {
          //here I store the response and my user data when register
      });
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? What are these "extra charges"?

Comment: @NolanH sorry for the delay. I mean The subscription plan is for have 3 types of services, in the new version of the app, we add that a person subscribe to have the 3 types of services and add 1 or 2 more but by apart, I don't know if I explain me

Comment: @NolanH For a example is that if you subscribe to our service, you can rent 3 cars for 9.99 but if you want you can add 1 or 2 cars by 3.99 extra per car, I want to know how can I make the charge for that extra with ngx-stripe